# sending byteArray in a JSON body via angularjs http request

Tags: angularjs, httprequest

I want to send a post request in which the body of request is a JSON included two attributes , one of them is canvas information generated with fabricjs and the second one is a byteArray of project thumbnail. the problem is that, when I send the request , I receive `null` in server side.

```
var dataURI = this.getDataUrl($rootScope.imageType, $rootScope.imageQuality);
var strImage = dataURI.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
var byteArray = covertBase64ToByteArray(strImage);

var data = {
  data: {
    name: name,
    state: canvas.fabric.toJSON(['selectable', 'name']),
    zoom: canvas.zoom,
    canvasWidth: width,
    canvasHeight: height,
  },
  typeArray: byteArray
};

$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: _url,
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  processData: false,
  transformRequest: [],
  contentType: 'application/json',
})
```

backend Code in .Net

```
public IHttpActionResult InsertOrUpdateUILayout(long user_Id, long layout_Id, int userLayout_Id, int? layoutType_Id, UserlayoutContentVM data)
{
    // back end code here
}

public class UserlayoutContentVM
{
    public object data { get; set; }
    //public string base64Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] typeArray{ get; set; }      
}
```

Comment: please share the backend api code aswell

Comment: @MarcusHöglund DONE

Answer (score 0):

When posting data to the backend api you need to tell the method to read the data from the request body.
This can be done with the `FromBody` attribute which will map the body data to the define model.

So add all properties to one model

```
public class UserlayoutContentVM
{
    public long user_Id { get; set; }
    public long layout_Id { get; set; }
    public int userLayout_Id { get; set; }
    public int? layoutType_Id { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }
    public byte[] typeArray{ get; set; }
}
```

Then make sure the client send all data in the same structure and use the FromBody attribute in the controller method to read the values

```
public IHttpActionResult InsertOrUpdateUILayout([FromBody]UserlayoutContentVM data){ }
```